# How do I format a timestamp into MM-DD-YYYY?

Tags: php

I'm building a page that displays transactions using API.
I have the following code atm:

```
/* Transactions */
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://nodes.wavesnodes.com/transactions/address/3PBqH72f4Nkf9K5cEvsNaKttYbqMLFDrqa4/limit/5",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "cache-control: no-cache"
  ),
));

$responseB1 = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

$dataB1 = json_decode($responseB1, true); // Because of true, it's in an array.

/* Transaction 0 */
echo '<br>Date: ' . $dataB1[0][0]['timestamp'];
```

The `echo` returns `Date: 1520348611194`

My question is how can I alter the output to format that timestamp into a MM-DD-YYYY date?

Thanks.

Comment: Read about [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) or, even better, [`DateTime::format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your timestamp is a unix timestamp, but in milliseconds. You need to remove the milliseconds so it's in seconds, and then use the PHP [`date`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function like so:

```
echo '<br>Date: ' . date('m-d-Y', $dataB1[0][0]['timestamp'] / 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `date` function.

```
echo date("m-d-Y", $dataB1[0][0]["timestamp"]);
```